# Unable to make any changes to view.py file

Tags: python, django, server, webserver, notepad++

I'm hosting a web server with `Django` framework .

Then , I'm using `Notepad++ NppFTP` to modify and upload those files .

I can modify the `html` files and upload to ftp server instantly with `Notepad++ NppFTP`  .But for updating `view.py` , I found that even though it says  `view.py` 100% upload success , the web seems to be unchanged regarding to the new `view.py` file .

Is that the way to modify the `view.py` file different to modifying `HTML` files ?

Comment: Did you restart the django server (gunicorn, I suppose)? If it's not restarted, it doesn't reload changed code files.

Comment: @FoolsWisdom Oh really ?  I m using linode . You mean I have to restart the server to make the view.py update ? But for html file ,no need .Is that right?

Comment: You don't need yo restart the linode server, only the python process running django (that's what I meant by server). Now, during development, you would use django's dev server, which automatically restarts itself when you change a file, but gunicorn won't do that. As for html files, I suppose that those are read frim the filesystem every time they are needed, so) but I could be wrong and django actually holds the html files in memory.

Comment: @FoolsWisdom So , what so I do the make the new `view.py` activate ?

Comment: You need to stop gunicorn and restart it. I don't know how you would do this though, it depends on how you setup gunicorn/django, and I'm afraid I never had to set one up myself, so I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any issues modifying a views.py file.  Check your permissions on the file and double check the directory you're uploading it to.

If you're on Linux,  in a terminal type ll (the letter L) and see who owns the file and directory.

Comment: Checked , View.py: for owner ,Read :ticked write ticked execute:no tick